# Car shutting down on its own while driving

Tags: engine-load

My car is Santro xing (2003 , 1 lakh+ distance). Recently i am facing a problem that it is shutting down on its own while driving. Any specific reason?

Comment: I assume by 1lakh+ distance you mean it's got 100,000 miles + on the odometer? Also can you provide more information on the symptoms you experience?

Comment: With just the information in your post as it stands I'd take a guess at a fuel supply issue - the fuel pumps on the Xing have been known to have overheating issues (which is why it cuts out after you've been driving for a while)

Comment: It stops when i change the gear usually from 1 to 2. And it gives a random jerks as if it is going to stop like during a push start.

Comment: Hmmm.. if it *only* happens when changing gear it could be clutch/transmission related but the random jerking still has me thinking fuel pump.

Comment: @Rishabh can you elaborate with any more detail?  Is the Check Engine Light (CEL) on?  If so, what are the codes?  You can take it to your local parts store and borrow their code reader.  Are the engine gauges all reading normally?  (You aren't overheating, and the engine generally shifts normally.)  You can edit your question with any more details you can think of.  Thanks!

Comment: And welcome to the site!